# C++ struct initialization assertion fails

Tags: c++, struct, assert

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
struct AStruct 
{ 
    int x; 
    char* y; 
    int z; 
};
int main()
{ 
    AStruct structu = {4, "Hello World"};
    assert(structu.z == ???);
}
```

What should I write in place of `???` to have a successful assertion?
I used `assert(structu.z == 0);` but unfortunately got the error
`int main(): Assertion 'structu.z == 0 failed.Aborted'`

Comment: What do you want to test? You don't write assertions unless you want something to be asserted!

Comment: amit no sir its not homework.

Comment: This is not a real question. Voted to close.

Comment: How is this not a real question?  He's asking a well-defined question with testable answer - +1, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: I just tried to replace ??? with 0 and the code ran successfully, what compilator are you using?

Comment: @Nicklas: It would have to be a broken one, because that assertion should never trigger for the code provided.

Comment: Well, what do you want to assert?

Comment: With your compiler and settings, what is the value of z after the struct is initialized?

Comment: How come you are not getting a compilation error for such initialization?

Comment: @VJo: what error do you expect?

Comment: @VJo: that is a legal initialization and should have defined behavior of z being value initialized to 0.

Comment: @seam strange. With proper flags passed to the compiler, it will always be marked as an error

Comment: @VJo: what compiler and flags?

Comment: @sean g++ 4.3+ with -Wall should do

Comment: As to which compilers might get that wrong... I believe that VS will if the struct is defined as `struct test { std::string s; int u; }; test t = { "Hi there" };`. IIRC there were a couple of corner cases in VS around aggregate initialization where the compiler would fail to correctly *value-initialize* some members.

Comment: @VJo: interesting.  I don't have g++ so can't confirm.  Odd that it marks it an error.

Answer (score 5):

You want:

```
 assert(structu.z == 0);
```

Your code assigns to the z member instead of testing it. And if you did get the message your edited question says you did, your compiler is broken. Which one is it?

Comment: @Neo: I don't believe that `assert(structu.z == 0)` gave you the message `Assertion: structu.z = int() failed`...

Comment: Why was this downvoted when other answers that say the same thing were upvoted?

Answer (score 3):

By "successful", I'm assuming you mean one that *doesn't* create an error message.  You probably want:

```
assert(structu.z == 0);
```

Note that I'm using `==`, and not `=`.

This assertion should never trigger, because with the code given, `structu.z` is guaranteed to be equal to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

`assert(structu.z == 0)` should work because the member `z` would be value initialized.